# How to add Meera Malayalam unicode font in blogger

Tags: fonts, font-face, blogger

We have a blog in blogger.com. Now we are using georgia font to show my Malayalam content, But it look's bad and can't read properly. We have used Meera font for malayalam in another website, but it is hosted in our own server. Here the issue is, blogger don't allow to upload files. We have the font in ttf format. How can I show my content in Meera font instead of georgia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the font in your server, you can call it to blogger blog or to any other webpage with CSS.

```
@font-face{font-family:Meera;src:url("//your-server/Meera.eot")}
@font-face{font-family:Meera;src:local('meera'),url('//your-server/Meera.ttf') format("truetype")}
```

and apply the font to any html element.

```
p{font-family:meera,georgia;}
```

Here is the [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Aslamise/Feea6/) that shows malayalam in meera font.

Hope this helps. 
If it helped you, Upvote for this answer. :)

Comment: I tried the same. But firefox and internet explorer not supporting cross browser @fontface css request

Answer (score 0):

Place the font in the Server and add this to the page.

```
@font-face {
font-family: sans;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
src: url(Meera.eot);
}

@font-face {
font-family: Meera;
src: local('Meera'), url('Meera.ttf') format("truetype");
}
```